# Default selected value for Ember.Select using belongsTo Ember Data model property?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

What I'm trying to do seems like a very common use case of Ember.Select, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm trying to set the default value of Ember.Select using a belongsTo Ember Data property. I have the following Ember.Select view in my template:

```
{{view Ember.Select content=neighborhoodOptions value=neighborhood.id optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.label"}}
```

The controller for this view looks like:

```
App.PropertyEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    neighborhoodOptions: [{value: 1, label: 'Foo'}, {value: 2, label: 'Bar'}]
});
```

I am using Ember Data and have a model with a belongsTo property for this controller which looks like:

```
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Property = DS.Model.extend({
    neighborhood: DS.belongsTo('neighborhood')
});
```

However, this does not set any default option when the page loads. What's worse, it makes the neighborhood.id undefined when I look the neighborhood model in the Ember Inspector console. If I remove the value attribute from the view, the neighborhood.id is defined again so it seems that the Ember.Select value property behavior is setting the id to undefined. I do not understand why it is doing this.

How can I bind the neighborhood id property and make it the default Ember.Select choice?

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in emberjs documentation. Please go through documentation 
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#toc_the-content-property-array-of-objects

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I have already looked through the documentation and it hasn't helped in this scenario. I think the best thing to do for the time being is just to use the selection property as the value property seems to be buggy.

Comment: hey can you put your code in jsbin may be that help more

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`selection=neighborhood`

Instead of `value`.  That way itll bind to that model instance rather than just the id value.